# SMB file server on multiple network cards

Tags: networking, powershell, hyper-v

We received two servers with hyper-V 2012R2 free for our project this week, and we need to create an SMB failover. I'm not familiar with multiple network card setups, as we had our previous servers with a single NIC.

How can I configure properly the settings in PowerShell to transfer the data over multiple network connections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add MPIO feature and configure multipathing. Here’s the detailed guide about SMB, find the MPIO configuration: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/part-2-smb-3-0-file-server-on-free-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-clustered.

Here’s an info about MPIO as well http://www.itprocentral.com/mpio-on-hyper-v-server/.

Also, make sure you don’t use LACP with the iSCSI because of possible latency issues.